# Linux Mint 17.3 Stuck In Software Rendering Mode on MacBook Pro

Tags: linux-mint, macintosh, amd-graphics

I've been happily running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro for awhile now.  Recently I was forced to wipe my computer so I thought I'd give Linux Mint a try. While everything is installed and running mostly well, I can't seem to stop Linux Mint from running in software rendering mode.

Didn't have much luck Googling around. I tried switching my AMD/ATI driver to `fglrx-updates` and `fglrx` but both fail to even work, instead booting Linux Mint to command line instead.

Machine Info:
Macbook Pro 8,2 
Dual booted (OS X El Capitan and Linux Mint 17.3)
Using Refind and grub config edit with nomodeset

My graphics card:
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]